# Home directory for user nobody - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, users, home-directory

I see a difference in the behaviour of the user "nobody" between Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04.

In both (18.04 and 20.04) versions, the user nobody is configured as:

```
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

In 18.04, for crontab applications, the home directory for nobody will be defined as `HOME=/`. In 20.04, crontab applications will report the home directory for nobody as non existent like

```
Failed to create secure directory (/nonexistent/.config/pulse): No such file or directory.
```

This is another example:

Ubuntu 18.04:

```
su - nobody
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
This account is currently not available.
```

Ubuntu 20.04:

```
su - nobody
su: warning: cannot change directory to /nonexistent: No such file or directory
This account is currently not available.
```

I guess that in 20.04 there is no default definition for users that have no valid home directory defined. How can we fix Ubuntu 20.04 so that it behaves like 18.04 (No directory, logging in with HOME=/).

Comment: `nobody` started as a fix for NFS - it mapped remote client `root` to `nobody` to avoid remote client `root` having `root` access to the server. Through feature creep, `nobody` has come to be used as a more general "no resources" account. Trying to use `nobody` via `su` and worrying about a home directory, etc is against `nobody`'s purpose. Don't do it.

Comment: Hi, I understand this. But this aside, where does the difference come from?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to make Ubuntu 20.04 `su` behave like Ubuntu 18.04 `su`.

The difference is because in Ubuntu 20.04/Focal `su` is provided by the `util-linux` package.  In Ubuntu 18.04/Bionic `su` is provided by the `login` package (built from the source package `shadow`).

```
root@ubuntu:~# lsb_release -r
Release:        18.04
root@ubuntu:~# dpkg -S /bin/su
login: /bin/su
```

```
root@ubuntu:~# lsb_release -r
Release:        20.04
root@ubuntu:~# dpkg -S /bin/su
util-linux: /bin/su
```

A key implementation difference appears to be support for `DEFAULT_HOME` in `/etc/login.defs`.  The [manpage for Bionic's `su`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/su.1.html) mentions in its **Configuration** section

```
       DEFAULT_HOME (boolean)
           Indicate if login is allowed if we can't cd to the home directory. Default is no.

           If set to yes, the user will login in the root (/) directory if it is not possible to
           cd to her home directory.
```

The [manpage for Focal's version of `su`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/su.1.html) does not mention `DEFAULT_HOME`.

I found a few relevant entries in [the changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/shadow/shadow_4.8.1-1ubuntu5/changelog) for the `shadow` package

```
  * Use explicit --without-su configure flag
 -- Balint Reczey <rbalint@ubuntu.com>  Fri, 20 Dec 2019 16:39:40 +0100
...
  * Drop Lintian override for su, it is not shipped in login anymore
 -- Balint Reczey <rbalint@ubuntu.com>  Mon, 08 Jul 2019 15:58:46 +0200
...
  * Stop shipping su and break old util-linux version. (See #833256)
 -- Andreas Henriksson <andreas@fatal.se>  Fri, 27 Jul 2018 10:07:37 +0200
```

It looks like the change was made upstream in Debian and coordinated in https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=833256 . The lack of `DEFAULT_HOME` support is mentioned but is not considered a blocker.